# Rewrite method signature to avoid having to call .asInstanceOf on client code

Tags: scala, types

In this code piece below I understand why I must call `asInstanctOf` in order to be able to call `bazMethod` from the class `Baz`:

```scala
class Bar[BR]
class Baz extends Bar[Int] {
  def bazMethod: Unit = {}
}

def map[A, B](args: Seq[Bar[A]])(f: Bar[A] => B): Seq[B] = args.map(f)

//Client Code
val bazes = Seq(new Baz)
map(bazes)(b => b.asInstanceOf[Baz].bazMethod)
```

However what I want to know is whether there's a way to rewrite this such that the client code doesn't have to use the `asInstanceOf`. **Just one condition:** I need the reference to `Bar[A]` to be available to me somehow inside the method. imagine this was a more complex method in which stuff need to be done base on what `A` Actually is.

Comment: Why not use inheritance and define abstract `bazMethod` in `Bar`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz In the actual code that I'm working on the corresponding class to ```Bar``` is actually in some third party library. I'm only free to modify ```Baz```. also I would like to verify the existence of a  solution through type parameters before I went for inheritance u know. It has learning value for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `map` accept `T <: Bar[_]` then it should work:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Bar[BR]
class Baz extends Bar[Int] {
    def bazMethod: Unit = {}
}

def map[B, T <: Bar[_]](args: Seq[T])(method: T => B): Seq[B] = args.map(method) 

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Bar
defined class Baz
map: [B, T <: Bar[_]](args: Seq[T])(method: T => B)Seq[B]

scala> val bazes = Seq(new Baz)
bazes: Seq[Baz] = List(Baz@225129c)

scala> map(bazes)(b => b.bazMethod)
res0: Seq[Unit] = List(())
```

Otherwise, as @Jasper-M has noted, if you want access to the type parameter `A` you would do something like this:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Bar[BR]
class Baz extends Bar[Int] {
    def bazMethod: Unit = {}
}

def map[B, T <: Bar[A], A](args: Seq[T with Bar[A]])(method: T => B): Seq[B] = args.map(method)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Bar
defined class Baz
map: [B, T <: Bar[A], A](args: Seq[T with Bar[A]])(method: T => B)Seq[B]

scala> val bazes = Seq(new Baz)
bazes: Seq[Baz] = List(Baz@341814d3)

scala>  map(bazes)(b => b.bazMethod)
res0: Seq[Unit] = List(())
```

Comment: thank you this certainly did  eliminate the need for ```asInstanceOf```. But I  have lost access to the parameter ```A``` which I really need. any solution  for that?

Comment: See my edit, you would need to add the type parameter to `Baz`

Comment: In `class Baz[Int] extends Bar[Int]` the `Int` now no longer refers to the integer type. It is equal to `class Baz[T] extends Bar[T]`.

Comment: Hmm, so what would be the appropriate signature? `class Baz[_] extends Bar[_]`?

Comment: @evan058 `class Baz extends Bar[Int]`. But you have to help type inference to infer `A` correctly: `def map[B, T <: Bar[A], A](args: Seq[T with Bar[A]])(method: T => B): Seq[B] = args.map(method)`

Comment: @Jasper-M thanks, I updated the answer with your note.